# query not working only when inside WITH ... AS statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I have a pretty difficult query to ask so I want to use the WITH ... AS syntax to break it down to smaller steps. I am trying to build a dummy query to ses how it works, which basically selects the stations that belong to a certain company and just selects everything again.

```
WITH company_stations AS (
    SELECT * FROM Station WHERE Station.stationProvider = 'olympia_odos'
) SELECT *  FROM  company_stations;
```

the inside query works fine on it's own

```
SELECT * FROM Station WHERE Station.stationProvider = 'olympia_odos'
```

But when I use it Inside the with as statement it gives me the very helpful error message

**ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'company_stations AS (SELECT stationName FROM Station WHERE Station.stationProvid' at line 1**

I tried searching for the ERROR 1064 (42000) but it seems that everyone that faced this error was in the process of building, populating or accessing a DB. I have done all these things, but the specific query seems to be problematic.

Also I tried all the usual suspects such as ' or " or `, ( or no ( etc.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.36, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: The WITH clause is supported only in version 8.0+

Comment: Comon table expression support is only available in MySql 8+. You'll need to use a derived table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CTE expressions is not supported before MySQL 8.0
You can use sub-queries instead:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Station WHERE Station.stationProvider = 'olympia_odos'
) AS company_stations;
```